# Creating organic shape in grasshopper and rhino

Tags: nodes, grasshopper, rhino3d

I am relatively new  to rhino and grasshopper but have knowledge about 3d objects from some years in blender. I need to create an organic shape that looks something like the pictures at the bottom (Especially the first one and also that last one).
It is very important to me that it is tileable and 3d. I found some tutorials, but it's never something that really looks how I want it to. I thought about creating it somehow with a physics plugin like kangoroo but I don't know how. Also the repeating, tileable method would be hard there. I also thought about not even using grasshopper but creating that stylie with a subsurf. But It might not be the same.

I wanted to ask, if someone knows how to create such a pattern, and what way you would approach it. Do you have a tutorial or a script you could share with me ? Maybe also a website where part of it gets explained and I can read myself into it. Or maybe you could give me a rough node setup and I go step for step through it to understand it. I would be very grateful. And I would appreciate it alot. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some keywords to help with your searches: [grasshopper voronoi 3d](https://www.google.com/search?q=grasshopper+voronoi+3d)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also relatively new to Grasshopper, but also come from a Blender/Maya background, and have some experience with Rhino.

General note - parametric design with NURBs etc. is not at all similar to working with polys, but some of the ideas related to 3D such as point/vertex, curve/edge, surface/face, polysurface/mesh will still apply. The main thing you want to understand from there are the different data structures, since Grasshopper and other plugins all rely on passing different data types from one component to another, and doing some sort of transformation or calculation on it.

Maybe you can treat it as a pattern that you are applying to a surface - whether that surface is flat, or curved?

I don't think you need Kangaroo for this. Maybe you could even do it with just paneling tools, depending on your needs.

Have a look at these tutorials:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7ON4NhJvxQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH9Kffo_AmA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEsn12tqtkY

Otherwise to achieve something with Grasshopper, I think you should look up Grasshopper tutorials on voronoi patterns. There are 2 main approaches I can think of, once you generate the curves of the voronoi pattern (or whatever other pattern you end up using):

1. Flowing the pattern along a surface, and then cutting it out
2. Piping the lines directly

Some tutorials on YouTube:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC9JZTyIneo
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4i_BtGElWg4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BasqPYaRNSI

Sorry I couldn't be more help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use marching cubes wrapper, here's an example file and forum thread on this topic: https://www.grasshopper3d.com/profiles/blogs/marching-cubes-curve-wrapping-more-metaballs?id=2985220%3ABlogPost%3A993966&page=1#comments

Comment: Although theoretically this may answer the question, your answer should be self-sufficient. That is, you should cite the important content from the link and include it in the post. This will make your answer more valuable, and more likely to get upvotes. Thank you for understanding. See this help center article: [answer].